# dump of 32bit-process running on windows2003 enterprise x64 sp2

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, dump

I try analyse this dump with Windbg. But it can't show x86 callstack.
symbol path configed as:

```
srv*D:\dev_head\win_symbols*
```

Some command result:

```
0:000> !teb
Wow64 TEB32 at 000000007efdd000
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols                 ***
***                                                                   ***
***    In order for this command to work properly, your symbol path   ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: wow64!_TEB32                                  ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
error InitTypeRead( wow64!_TEB32 )...
Wow64 TEB at 000000007efdb000
ExceptionList:        000000007efdd000
StackBase:            000000000016fcfc
StackLimit:           000000000016b000
SubSystemTib:         0000000000000000
FiberData:            0000000000001e00
ArbitraryUserPointer: 0000000000230bf0
Self:                 000000007efdb000
EnvironmentPointer:   0000000000000000
ClientId:             00000000000007e0 . 0000000000000ecc
RpcHandle:            0000000000000000
Tls Storage:          0000000000000000
PEB Address:          000000007efdf000
LastErrorValue:       0
LastStatusValue:      0
Count Owned Locks:    0
HardErrorMode:        0


0:000> !load wow64exts
0:000> !sw
The current thread doesn't have an x86 context.
```

symbols file wow64.pdb, wow64win.pdb can download/load correctly, but only wow64cpu.pdb just can not download. Is this problem lead to analyse failure?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll want to configure both the symbol server from Microsoft and a downstream (local) cache location.

Example using a Samba/CIFS server in the local network (you have to be able to write to it):

```
symsrv*symsrv.dll*\\sambasrv\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

... or instead a disk location:

```
symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Windows\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Use `.symfix` in WinDbg to set the MS symbol server as default, then `.reload` to reload all the symbol information.

It is common to configure a global environment variable named `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`:

```
setx /s _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=symsrv*symsrv.dll*\\sambasrv\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

(the above is the batch/NT script syntax ... consult `setx /?`)

Also look at the command line switch `-y` for WinDbg if you, like I do, create shortcuts with various different command lines (e.g. to debug VMs).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a full dump and not a small memory dump file. The WOW64CPU Program database should be for [download](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/symbolpkg.mspx) with the Symbol Package libraries.

Force the loading of a particular pdb, with the following flags: (but be aware that the debug result may be erroneous at several points due to mismatches)

```
.reload /f [name] /i
```

Other developers have reported similar issues. 
See "[Unable to get the symbols file for wow64cpu.dll from 64-bit Windows 2003 Server SP2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windbg/thread/ba44ef7b-51a4-4660-ba60-7c8b27089d4e)"

- Do you run the x86 version of WinDBG?

You may also consider another Windows version running inside VirtualBox or VMWare.

**See also**:

[How to read the small memory dump files that Windows creates for debugging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263)

Comment: "Unable to get the symbols file for wow64cpu.dll from 64-bit Windows 2003 Server SP2" I had notice this issue.

Comment: I download WindowsServer2003-KB933548-v1-x64-symbols-NRL-ENU, and found that there is wow64win.pdb in it, but no wow64cpu.pdb. Is microsoft mistake?? @_@ I do use x86 version WinDBG...